# Ruby on Rails form with optional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the text_field form helper but it's not working. Here is my form

```
<%= form_for @score do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :site_id %> 
        <%= f.select(:value, (1..10).to_a) %>
        <%= f.text_field :response %>       
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

When I run this locally, I'm getting a NoMethodError for `:response`. `Response` is an attribute of `score` that I just added, so the problem might lie there.

This is what my `score_controller` looks like at the moment

```
 def create
    @score = Score.create(score_params)
    respond_with @score
  end

  def new
    @score = Score.new(site: Site.find(params['site_id']))
  end

  private

  def score_params
    params.require(:score).permit(:value, :response, :site_id)
  end
```

Now `response` isn't going to be a required field, the user can leave the response blank if they want to. Or at least that's what I want to it to be like. I'm new to rails; this is my first project using it.

Thanks

Edit: Here is my scores table, along with the error

```
create_table "scores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "value",      null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "site_id"
    t.string   "response"
  end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError at /scores/new
undefined method `response' for #<Score:0x007ff293567790>
Did you mean?  respond_to?
```

Edit2: Creating a new score in rails console

```
s = Score.new
=> #<Score:0x007fbec9001448 id: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, site_id: nil, response: nil>
```

Edit3: @score from `new` action

```
[1] pry(#<ScoresController>)> @score.inspect
=> "#<Score id: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, site_id: 130>"
[2] pry(#<ScoresController>)>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `response` is an `attribute` of `score`? Can you update the question with scores table schema?

Comment: Have you run the migration? rake db:migrate?

Comment: I added my scores table to the post

Comment: What is the exact and full error? Can you update it in the question?

Comment: Are you create the migration for response

Comment: yes I ran the migration for response

Comment: Just create a new object ofof score in rails console and post that

Comment: alright, added to post

Comment: Can you inspect `@score` in the `new` method and post the output in the question?

Comment: yup, just added that

Comment: Hmm. Everything looks ok. I'm guessing that `response` could be a reserve word in rails. Try @7urkm3n answer.

Comment: The problem is the object was created when the database has not the response field so you can delete that object and add new one it will work fine

Comment: I think I ended up re-running my migrations and then it started working

Answer (score 1):

Probably, rails catches own response object, try just rename it. `response_score`

```
<%= form_for @score do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :site_id %> 
        <%= f.select(:value, (1..10).to_a) %>
        <%= f.text_field :response_score %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
  def create
    @score = Score.create(score_params.merge(response: params[:score][:response_score]))
    respond_with @score
  end

  private

  def score_params
    params.require(:score).permit(:value, :site_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you had just added `:response`, but the migration for the `scores` table shows no additional migration for `:response`.

The return values from `new` also show that there's no `response` in the object, so that further indicates that the `response` column was never actually created.

Given what you've shown for the `scores` table migration, it looks like you have a migration definition issue.  The correct way to add a new DB column is to create a subsequent migration, as so:

```
rails generate migration AddResponseToScores
```

Once you've done that, you should have a new migration file in db/migrate.  Edit this file, as so:

```
class AddResponseToScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :scores do |t|
      t.string :response, limit: 1000, null: true
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I added the `limit` qualifier (allows you to restrict the column size) and made the `null` qualifier explicit, which helps to self-document the intent of the code.  I find that if you're building a 'real' application, these become important for maintainers; however, you're free to omit them as you see fit.

Once the editing is complete, you can run the migration, like so:

```
rake db:migrate
```

If that succeeds, I also run the rollback method and then migrate again, just to make sure that there are no issues with rolling back in case of deployment issues.  You can rollback your migration with this command:

```
rake db:rollback
```

That should make sure that the :response column is created properly.

Migration files like this allow you to make incremental changes to the database schema during the life cycle of the project.  Use migrations to add or remove columns, change column attributes (name, nullable, size, etc), add or remove indexes, and even add or drop tables.  You'll typically have at least a few of these, and may have quite a lot if you have a larger project.